# How to transverse string for numbers and assign then to variable

Tags: c, arrays

Hey so I have an array setup as:

```
char array_string[4][50];
```

Within this array:

```
array_string[0] = "C 0.21 0.87 0.66 0.34"
array_string[1] = "C 0.6 0.2 0.1 0.7"
array_string[2] = "A 5 9"
array_string[3] = "B 4 4"
```

I am just trying to write a loop that will scan through the array strings.
The loop has to first check if the starting letter is A OR B. If it is then it just extracts the 2 ints and stores them, however if the loop beings with C, then it has to extract all 4 decimal numbers. I am just very unsure of how to do this as the decimals can have one decimal point or 2 decimal point. I was going to just trasverse the string char by char but is there an easier way that will recognise the full number?

Comment: Loop checking the first character. For `int` use `strtol` to walk-down-the-string extracting integers. For `double` use `strtod` to walk-down-the-string extracting double precision floating point values. The number of decimal places does not matter. An alternative is to use `strtok` to `tokenize` each string and perform the conversion, or loop with `sscanf` keeping an `offset` from the beginning. However `strtol` and `strtod` were written for this purpose.

Comment: Where are you going to store the pairs of integers, and do you need to record the letter A or B?  Where are you going to store the quads of `double` (or were you going to use `float`?)?  What are you going to do if an `A` or `B` record has one integer, or three integers, or there are non-numeric characters?  Similarly with the `C` records?  These are the sorts of detail that make programming hard work, sadly, but they're also the difference between robust, reliable programs and fragile, unreliable programs.

Answer (score 2):

> is there an easier way that will recognize the full number?

`sscanf()` is versatile.

Code can use `"%n"` to log the scanning offset and detect completion.

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(string, "C %*f %*f %*f %*f %n", &n);
if (n > 0 && string[n] == '\0') {
  puts("String is of the form 4 decimal.");
}

n = 0;
sscanf(string, "%*[AB] %*d %*d %n", &n);
if (n > 0 && string[n] == '\0') {
  puts("String is of the form 2 integers.");
}
```

---

The `"*"` suppresses assignment.

Use the usual `"%f"` and matching `float *` argument to save the value.  Likewise for `"%d"`.